# Akka Persistence - Deletion not happening in LevelDB

Tags: akka, akka-persistence

Persistent Actor receiving one message at a time. After persisting 100 messages, it should send those 100 messages to destination Actor. I intend to delete those messages after saving a snapshot.

I am snapshotting after every 50 messages.I am deleting messages just after receiving SavingSnapshotSuccess.But deletion doesn't happen. I still see those messages in the logs being appended. Not receiving either DeleteMessagesSuccess/Failure Message. Also not receiving DeleteSnapshotsSuccess/Failure on deleting snapshots.

Following are the versions:

```
"com.typesafe.akka"%%   "akka-actor" % "2.4.0",
"com.typesafe.akka"%%   "akka-cluster"  % "2.4.0",
"com.typesafe.akka"%%   "akka-contrib"   % "2.3.14",
"com.typesafe.akka"%%   "akka-slf4j"% "2.4.0",
"com.typesafe.akka"%%   "akka-testkit"% "2.4.0" % "test",
"com.typesafe.akka"%%   "akka-persistence"   % "2.4.0"
```

Code:

```
class Consumer extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging{

  override def persistenceId = "bulkMessageConsumer-1"

  var state = BulkState()

  def updateState(event: Event): Unit = { 
    state = state.updated(event)
   }

  def numEvents = state.size

  val receiveRecover: Receive = {
   case evt: Event                                 => updateState(evt)
   case SnapshotOffer(_, snapshot: BulkState) => state = snapshot
  }

  val receiveCommand: Receive = {

case Snapshoot ⇒
  saveSnapshot(state)

  case sss @ SaveSnapshotSuccess(metadata) ⇒
  deleteMessages(toSequenceNr = metadata.sequenceNr - 1)
  deleteSnapshots(SnapshotSelectionCriteria(maxSequenceNr = metadata.sequenceNr - 1, maxTimestamp = metadata.timestamp - 1))

case SaveSnapshotFailure(metadata, reason) ⇒
  log.error(reason, "Unable to save snapshot [metadata: {}]", metadata)

case c @ Command(data) =>
  persistAsync(Event(c.data)) { event =>
    basicChecks
    updateState(event)
  }

case DeleteSnapshotsSuccess =>
   log.info("deleting snapshots")

case DeleteSnapshotsFailure =>
  log.info("deleting snapshots failure")

case dms @ DeleteMessagesSuccess =>
  log.info("messages deleted succesfully:")

case DeleteMessagesFailure =>
  log.info("messages deletion failure")

case Print =>
   println(state)
}

def send(): Unit ={
  val framedMessage = MyMessage
  DestinationActorRef ! framedMessage
  remove()
}

def remove(): Unit ={
  state = state.removeAll
}

def checkNumEventsReachBulkSize: Boolean ={
    numEvents==100
 }

 def checkSnapshotBatch :Boolean ={
    numEvents % 50 == 0 && numEvents >0
 }

 def basicChecks: Unit ={
    if(checkSnapshotBatch){
    self ! Snapshoot
 }

if(checkNumEventsReachBulkSize){
  send()
   }
 }

}
```